# Getting error after delete @ComponentScan from SpringBootApplication

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cron

I am using @ComponentScan on SpringBootApplication to run cron, below is my code

```
package com.ravi
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;
@org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages= {"com.ravi","com.ravi.cron"})
@EnableScheduling
public class SpringBootApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(SpringBootApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootApplication.class, args);       
    }

}
```

Cron :

```
package com.ravi.cron
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Lazy;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Lazy(false)
public class CleanDataJob {
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(CleanDataJob.class);
    @Autowired
    DeleteDataFromDatabase deleteData;
    @Scheduled
    public void deleteData() {
        // Cleaning data job code
        deleteData.cleanData();
    }
}
```

Below class is Autowired in cron

```
com.ravi.logic
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
@Service
public class DeleteDataFromDatabase {
  public void cleanData() {
     // Clean data code
 }
}
```

If want to delete @ComponentScan annotation from SpringBootApplication, but below error is showing

```
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/com.ravi]]
```

And second error is

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'cleanDataJob ': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'deleteData'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.ravi.logic.DeleteDataFromDatabase' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

After deleting @ComponentScan getting a 404 error on the web
On DeleteDataFromDatabase, checked with @Configuration, @Controller but not resolved

Comment: Have you tried adding `com.ravi.logic` package in your `@ComponentScan` of your main class?

Comment: Yes but same issue is getting

Comment: Are you sure your code is up to date? `DeleteDataFromDatabase deleteData;` and `Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'deleteDataFromDatabase'` indicate a mismatch.

Comment: @Thomas i have updated the code you can check now

Comment: If the package structure is really as you state it is, Spring Boot should detect everything already without the need for the `@ComponentScan`. So unless you have something different (also naming your class `SpringBootApplication` isn't the best name, judging also from the full import of the annotation) that you aren't showing.

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks for the suggestion, added full imports for the annotation

Comment: That isn't what I was suggesting... I was suggesting that naming your own application `SpringBootApplication` was a bad decision... Rename it to something else so uyou can use proper imports and not mistakenly use the wrong one somewhere.